# Collision between photon and an isolated electron

Tags: particle-physics, photons, electrons, collision

Consider an isolated electron and a photon of energy 'hf' suffers collision with it. Then will the electron absorb all the energy of the photon or some amount is absorbed? If so, then does the photon after collision has less frequency than the previous one?

Comment: Answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/358727/two-electrons-exchanging-a-photon - As @AnnaV has stated there, it is called Compton Scattering, "A photon interacts with the electron, the electron becomes off shell because it absorbs part of the four momentum of the incoming photon and a lower energy photon leaves". A full absorption is not possible without a violation of conservation of energy or momentum.

Comment: *"suffers collision with it"* - what does 'suffers collision' mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a photon scatters off a free electron,  it can either scatter elastically, i.e. no change in the frequency of the outgoing, or undergoes what is called Compton scattering. The distributions of the outgoing photonh can be calculated using the expansion in [Feynman diagrams](http://inspirehep.net/record/835700/plots) to first order :

[image: Compton scattering]

The outgoing photon will have a smaller frequency as the incoming transferred part of its momentum and energy to the electron. For the history see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).

Comment: So complete absorption of energy doesn't take place by the electron. Right?

Comment: Right, complete absorption will violate energy conservation in the center of mass, because the electron is an elementary particle ( no excited states) and its mass is fixed.

Comment: come to think of it also angular momentum conservation, as the spin1 of the photon cannot be accomodated by the electron at rest and alone.